# Select all entities where first item in relationshiptable has specific values

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using C# with Entity Framework 6.1.3 and SQL Server. I have the following entities:

```
public partial class Contract
{
    public Contract()
    {
        this.Records = new List<Record>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Record> Records { get; set; }
}

public partial class Record
{
    public Record()
    {
        this.Contracts = new List<Contract>();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Published { get; set; }
    public int RecordID { get; set; } // Primary key
    public int Version { get; set; } // Primary key
    public virtual ICollection<Contract> Contracts { get; set; }
}
```

They have a many-to-many relationship. A contract has many records and a record can be published or not. When a record is published the version is increased.

Now I want to select all `Contract` where the contracts `Record` with the highest `Version` with `Published` set to some date has `Name` and `Description` set to a specific value. I'm only interested in the Record with the highest `Version` that also have `Published` set to a value. The specific date for `Published` is not interesting.

Pseudo: Get contract where the last published record has name == "bar".

```
// Table data for Records (Description left out for sake of formatting)

RecordId | Name | Version | Published
1        | Bar  | 1       | 2015-01-01
1        | Foo  | 2       | 2015-02-01
1        | Bar  | 3       | 2015-03-01
1        | Foo  | 4       | 2015-04-01
1        | Bar  | 5       | 2015-05-01
1        | Bar  | 6       | 2015-06-01
1        | Foo  | 7       | 2015-07-01 // I want this one.
1        | Foo  | 8       | NULL // not interesting.
```

I tried this one at first:

```
var result =    context.Contracts.Where(
                    x =>
                        x.Records.Where(r => r.Published.HasValue)
                            .OrderByDescending(r => r.Version)
                            .FirstOrDefault(r => r.Name == "foo") != null);
```

But then it will actually just sort by version, and then check if there is any item with `Name == "foo"`, not the one with highest version that also is published, so the sort will not actually bring anything. So then I tried this:

```
var result =
    context.Contracts.Where(
        x =>
            x.Records.Where(r => r.Published.HasValue)
                .OrderByDescending(r => r.Version)
                .FirstOrDefault().Name == "foo");
```

Which is more correct, but now it may cause null-value exception. And I also want to check `Description` for a value, which would create this query:

```
var result =
    context.Contracts.Where(
        x =>
            x.Records.Where(r => r.Published.HasValue)
                .OrderByDescending(r => r.Version)
                .FirstOrDefault() != null && 
            x.Records.Where(r => r.Published.HasValue)
                .OrderByDescending(r => r.Version)
                .FirstOrDefault().Name == "foo" &&
            x.Records.Where(r => r.Published.HasValue)
                .OrderByDescending(r => r.Version)
                .FirstOrDefault().Description == "some value");
```

But it doesn't seem very efficient. Is there a better way?

Comment: Have you tried this?   .Where(r => r.Published.HasValue && r.Name == "foo" && r.Description == "some value").OrderByDescending(r=>r.version);

Comment: @DhananjayaKuppu > Not a bad idea. .Where(r => r.Published.HasValue && r.Name == "foo" && r.Description == "some value").OrderByDescending(r=>r.version).FirstOrDefault() != null; Could work. I'll test and get back to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `FirstOrDefault`, you can use `Take(1)` to limit the set and then apply the needed criteria using `Any`:

```
var result = context.Contracts
    .Where(x => x.Records
        .Where(r => r.Published.HasValue)
        .OrderByDescending(r => r.Version)
        .Take(1)
        .Any(r => r.Name == "foo" && r.Description == "some value"));
```

Comment: This actually renders a SQL query with "only" 35 reads compared to 305 reads when using FirstOrDefault() != null, which also uses OUTER APPLY. Good suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You could also try:

```
.Where(r => r.Published.HasValue && 
               r.Name == "foo" && 
          r.Description == "some value")
.Max(r => r.Version) != null
```

Comment: This will select the highest version, but not the entity that is related to it. Resharper wants to replace the code with .Where(x => true); since .Max(r => r.Version) always return true.